# How to merge dynamic forms with Adobe Livecycle?

Tags: merge, adobe, livecycle, dynamic-forms

I have a number PDF documents which are dynamic forms. I want to make one document that contains all pages of the fist document, then all pages of the second, and so on. How can I do it programmatically with the Java API of Adobe Livecycle Enterprise Server?

I found documentation here, but it does not work for dynamic forms. Maybe I can convert the dynamic forms to static forms first? How can I do that?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/help/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=sdkHelp&file=001473.html

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Cheers,
Arne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how many of these you need to create. I assume you are going to be making large numbers of these PDF's. The correct thing to use is Adobe LC Output ES2. The process is first to render your dynamic XFA based forms to static PDF using the Output service with whatever data you have and then to assemble them with the Assembler service (requires a DDX file with the rules for the assembly).

There are APIs (inc. Java) to call these services directly or you can write an orchestration(in Workbench) that does all the steps and you can call the orchestration from various API's including Java. The short lived orchestration capability is also licensed with Output.

This sample would be a good thing to review to see how to construct the orchestration (service) XDP and DDX.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/samples/ServiceUsageSampleOutputLetterWithAttachment.html

Places to review invoking orchestrations in Java are:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/000495.html

Best of luck C.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

1. Add a numeric field to the master pages
2. Mark it as `calculated - read only`
3. Select current page number, in the menu below. you can also have another with total number of pages.